# Root user takes unison profile from regular user?

Tags: unison

I have two unison profiles with the same name as following:

```
/root/.unison/theprofile.prf
/home/users/itsme/.unison/theprofile.prf
```

Both have different contents. They target the same remote server (over SSH), but have their own directory on that server.

I execute the following:

```
sudo unison theprofile
```

I expected that the profile in `/root/.unison/theprofile.prf` was taken, but some reason I do not understand the profile in `/home/users/itsme/.unison/theprofile.prf` was taken.

Why is that? How can I allow `root` to have its own unison profile, without conflicting the profile of `itsme` (and vice versa)? Ideally, they don't even know anything from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use just `sudo`, you switch the user, but you keep the environment variables from the old user. So the config file from `itsme` is used, because that's still the current home directory.

If you want to completely switch to root, including all environment variables, you have to run sudo with the `-i` parameter so it creates a login shell.

```
sudo -i unison theprofile
```

Then it will use the profile from the root home directory.

Comment: TIL `sudo -i` to start fresh